# iOS app become unresponsive when add overlays on mapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, ios10, mkoverlay

I'm using MKPolygon to draw a overlay on MKMapView. It was working fine in iOS 9, after update Xcode and iOS to to Xcode 8 and iOS 10 , its not working and make app unresponsive
Overley count is 90. is it problematic ?
here my code , take a look

```
    - (void)addOverlaysOnMap
{
    NSMutableArray<MKPolygon *> *array = [NSMutableArray new];

  //here arrRegions is NSMutableArray has json data in model form 
    for (int i = 0; i < arrRegions.count; i++) {

        RegionModel *rModel = arrRegions[i];

        [array addObject:[self getPolygon:rModel]];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
        MKPolygon *poly = array[i];
        [regionMapView addOverlay:poly];

    }


 -(MKPolygon *)getPolygon:(RegionModel *)rModel{
    NSLog(@"%@",rModel.coordinates);

    if (rModel.coordinates == nil) {
        rModel.coordinates = @"";
    }

    NSArray *arrCoordinates = [rModel.coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];


    if (arrCoordinates.count > 0) {


        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[arrCoordinates.count];
        int index = 0;
        for (NSString *strCoordinate in arrCoordinates) {

            NSArray *coordinate = [strCoordinate componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

            coordinates[index] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([coordinate.firstObject doubleValue], [coordinate.lastObject doubleValue]);

            index++;
        }

      MKPolygon *polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:coordinates count:arrCoordinates.count];

        if (rModel.stateid == 0) {
            NSLog(@"no stateID");
        }

        polygon.accessibilityHint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.f,%0.f, %@",rModel.regionid,rModel.stateid, rModel.regionname];


        return polygon;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }

}
```

here is my MKOverlay delegate

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {

    MKPolygonRenderer *render = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc]initWithOverlay:overlay];
    render.lineWidth = 2;

    render.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:195.0f/255.0f blue:79.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

return render;

    }
```

please help me to figure out whats the issue and how to resolve.

Comment: Can you add the log outputs from running this?  Hard to know what the issue is without knowing what polygons you're drawing on the view.  Also, I'm assuming that it's not the app itself that's unresponsive, but rather the map view?  Are you doing anything that traps map touch events?